# Selected Json Fields Ignore

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

when I requested from a table with one-to-one relationship, I want only one fields back to me. I used `JsonIgnore` but it's ignored all fields.

example:

```
@Entity
 public class Application {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Name cannot be blank")
    String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email cannot be blank")
    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "Phone cannot be blank")
    String phone;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Job job;

}
```

but I need a annotations like this = `JsonIgnoreExcept(Job.Title)`

how can I do that?

Comment: You can't. You need to annotate each feld in Job that you don't want which will give you `{...{job: "title"...`

Answer (score 0):

*I need a annotations like this = JsonIgnoreExcept(Job.Title)*

You can't. You need to annotate each feld in Job that you don't want which will give you

```
{...
   job: {"title" : "someTitle"}
...}
```

Alternatively you can use a Spring Data's projection

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

where is would be possible to get:

```
{...
   "job": "someTitle"
...}

@Projection
public interface ApplicationSummary{
    //all other fields you want

    @Value("#{target.job.title}")
    public String getJob();
}
```

The drawback of the above is you need to specify all required fields in your projection interface.

A better alternative for the 2nd form then is possibly to use a Jackson converter.

```
@Entity
public class Application {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonDeserializer(converter = CustomJobConverter.class)
    private Job job;
}
```

with converter:

```
public class CustomerJobConveter implements StdConverter<Job, String>{

    public String convert(Job job){
        return job.getTitle();
    }
}
```